# CSS transition briefly causes element to be "hoverable" after being made hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, css-transitions

I have a link that when you hover on top, should display a drop down menu. I would like for this drop down menu to have a transition while appearing/disappearing. Currently, when I hover on the link, the drop down menu transitions in, and when I move the cursor away from the link, it transitions out. The problem is that the drop down menu, once hidden again, is still "hoverable" for a brief moment, causing it to reappear when I hover in the location where it would be were it visible (see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/monroewebdev/jogag3Lb/).

I believe this is due to a lag caused by the exit transition. When I remove transition effects, I do not have this issue. Is there a way to keep the transition effects without causing this lag upon exit? Can I maybe speed up the exit transition? How would I do this?

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Rates & Services</a>
       <div class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="#">Website Design</a>
           <a href="#">Website Maintenance</a>
           <a href="#">Ecommerce Sites</a>
           <a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a>
           <a href="#">More Services</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- list continues on -->
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ed393c;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -moz-transition: 500ms;
    -ms-transition: 500ms;
    -o-transition: 500ms;
    transition: 500ms;
}
```

JQuery 2.2.2

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown .dropbtn').css('background-color', '#ed393c');
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-content').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-content').css('opacity', '1');
}, function() {
    $('.dropdown .dropbtn').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-content').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-content').css('opacity', '0');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily disable the hover behavior by applying `pointer-events: none` on the dropdown content when you stop hovering.

However, that also means you have to explicity set the transition to include the `visibility` and `opacity`, but exclude the `pointer-events`, otherwise the hover will only be disabled *after* the animation ends (and that's exactly not what you want)

#### jQuery:

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown .dropbtn').css('background-color', '#ed393c');
    // Using a shorthand here to set multiple CSS properties at once
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-content').css({
        visibility: 'visible',
        opacity: 1,
        pointerEvents: 'initial'
    });
}, function() {
    $('.dropdown .dropbtn').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-content').css({
        visibility: 'hidden',
        opacity: 0,
        pointerEvents: 'none'
    });
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-content {
   visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #ed393c;
   -webkit-transition: visibility 500ms, opacity 500ms;
   -moz-transition: visibility 500ms, opacity 500ms;
   -ms-transition: visibility 500ms, opacity 500ms;
   -o-transition: visibility 500ms, opacity 500ms;
   transition: visibility 500ms, opacity 500ms;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jogag3Lb/2/)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I knew there was a simple solution for this!